# Boost.asio async tcp_connection

Tags: boost, boost-asio

```
error: invalid use of incomplete type 'class boost::enable_shared_from_this<tcpConnection>'
```

So I've been following [this](http://think-async.com/Asio/boost_asio_1_10_2/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial.html) - the 'tutorial' section of the documentation - and got to the [async tcp server](http://think-async.com/Asio/boost_asio_1_10_2/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tutdaytime3.html), and ran into the above error when doing;

```
class tcpConnection:public enable_shared_from_this<tcpConnection>
```

I ctrl-C ctrl-V 'ed the tcpConnection code (or rather tcp_connection - I changed it to camelcase) and had the *same* error.

Comment: Are you including the `boost/enable_shared_from_this.hpp` header file, as is done in the [full source listing](http://think-async.com/Asio/boost_asio_1_10_2/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tutdaytime3/src.html)?

Comment: Oh! I'll try that tomorrow morning! Thanks!

Comment: Worked - forgot to say. :-P

Answer (score 0):

It is not a difficult error, please check following things.

1. Are you including `#include <boost/enable_shared_from_this.hpp>` ?
2. And also, Are you using namespace `boost` ?

Please try this solutions, And if you failed tell me please.

Best regards.